# Web Service vs Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin, webservice-client

I'm a c# developer, I've to build a mobile app with Xamarin and I've to call a server to read and write data.
I don't know if create a Web Service or a Web API server side, which's the best solution?
I tried to search online and I've found many suggestions but I don't understand which's the best.

Comment: Full-fledged SOAP web services (WCF) are pretty strong when it comes to server-to-server interop - but for reaching out to clients, especially mobile clients, I'd go with ASP.NET Web API and a REST style of service calls

Comment: What's "best" is going to be opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly both are means for communications like between two applications or electronic devices over http the World Wide Web
[image]

All **web services** are APIs look in above figure
**All APIs** are not web services.

**Host:** Web-services(Means web internet) can only be hosted on IIS-
But API -Application Programming Interface can be hosted within an application or IIS because it is an application approach.-

**Open Source**
Web-services is an not opensource (mean it use via IIS).
API is an open source(when use with in application, and when use on http is not)

**Design Pattern**
Web-services based on Protocal
API is based on architectural style(so it use with in application)

https://om9x.com/blog/web-services-vs-api/

Comment: Question is about 'Web API' not about only 'API'

Comment: By the way web service does not mean that it is only hosted on 'IIS'. It means it offers service over web protocols. If any query follow link :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service

Answer (score 0):

IMO, ASP.NET Web API is a Web (HTTP) Service already.

Go to [Learn About ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api), you will find at the top:

> ASP.NET Web API is a framework that makes it easy to build HTTP
>   services that reach a broad range of clients, including browsers and
>   mobile devices. ASP.NET Web API is an ideal platform for building
>   RESTful applications on the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

if by web service you mean .asmx web services, they are being replaced with WebAPI. I also recommend you to check NancyFX for API creation.